# Validating Rails form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I am trying to validate form before the form submission, but the form get's submitted and the `jQuery` part is not called.

```
<%= form_for(:session,class:"form-signin form-horizontal",:id=>
  "form",:role=>
  "form") do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-mardin-bottom">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
      </i>
    </span>
    <%= f.text_field :email,class:"form-control required",:placeholder=>
      "username or email", name:"username"%>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-mardin-bottom">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
        </i>
      </span>
      <%= f.password_field :password,class:"form-control required",:placeholder=>
        "password", password:"password" %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group login-page-margin-10">
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
          <%= f.submit "Sign In", :class =>
            "btn btn-success" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12 control">
            <hr/>
            <div>
              <a href="#">
                <strong>
                  Forgot your password?
                </strong>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <%end%>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("#form").validate({

});
```

The jQuery validate method is not called at all.

Comment: Did you have set `Onsubmit` or `Onclick` call for a `function` while submitting the `form`?

Comment: @Pavan: I have updated my entire form.

Comment: Scratch that.Is that all you have in the `jQuery code`?

Comment: @Pavan: Yes, i am trying to validate the code before form submissin.

Comment: Maybe this working exemple could help you http://jsfiddle.net/Vcmfs/98/

Comment: @Nanego: that would work, but when using rails form helper it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its in rails 3, but preload `@session` object in your action and try

```
<%= form_for @session , html: { id: "form", class: "form-signin form-horizontal", role: "role" } do |f| %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this example should help you.Try this with your `form`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(“#new_user”).validate({
debug: true,
rules: {
“user[email]“: {required: true, email: true},
“user[password]“: {required: true, minlength: 6},
“user[password_confirmation]“: {required: true, equalTo: “#user_password”}
}
});
});
```

**[Source](http://bestror.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/validation-form-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery-validate/)**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the jquery validate plugin ?

If not, you can use this gem:

```
gem "jquery-validation-rails"
```

and add the following to your application.js file if your are using the asset pipeline:

```
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
```